# Testflight not working for iOS 8

Tags: ios8, testflight

While working with `iOS 7`, we never had these issues, but since `iOS 8` has come in, we have noticed a lot of problems with our testers.
With `iOS 7`, whenever new device/tester joined our team, we would create a new provisioning certificate with apple, and update it on testflight. It would seamlessly let `iOS 7` users know that the build was updated, and they were easily able to use it.
But now when a `iOS 8` user tries to download the build, the error that he gets is, as if his `UDID` was never added to the build, although in provisioning certificate, it is clearly listed.
I have seen a couple of questions related to this but couldn't find a clear solution.
Currently the workaround I am doing is, everytime a `iOS 8` user joins in, I have to create a new build using the new provisional certificate, and upload it again on testflight.
Its getting worse now, because number of our testers is increasing day by day.

I am using `XCode 5.1.1 (5B1008)` to create the builds.

Comment: Maybe you should try using 'XCode 6.0.1'

Comment: I wasn't even aware you could update the profile. I've been using the desktop app to upload, but with the new iOS 8.1 / Xcode 6.1, that's broken too. I wouldn't hold my breath for a fix, Apple is busy moving testflight into iTunes Connect. I'm just hoping they enable external testers soon. I'm using [betabuilder](http://www.hanchorllc.com/betabuilder-for-ios/) as a stop gap replacement for testflight while I wait for apple.

Comment: Even worse now. Can't even see the Update profile link on Permissions page.

Comment: Fixed with the latest itunes connect update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Apple acquired TestFlight, they changed the whole process for iOS 8:

- No more provisionning profiles, only Apple ID's email.
- 1,000 beta testers and 25 internal testers per application.
- https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ is the new testflightapp.com/dashboard/
- You need to use Xcode 6 to handle iOS 8

I have successfully replaced my old process by following this one: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-beta-testing-with-testflight--cms-22224